# No sound (VIA ac97)

Tags: windows-7, audio

One day I switched off my computer and the next day the sound was gone. Speakers worked on another device, sound hardware is detected, software and speakers volume is on and the mixer bar shows the blue moving bar when the something should be being heard. My sound controller also detects correctly whether the speakers are plugged in.

But simply there is no sound.

Hardware: the motherboard is ASUS P5P77 LX.
Software: Windows 7 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the speaker icon in the system tray and select playback devices.  Make sure whatever you are using (probably should just say "Speakers") has a green check.  If not highlight it and select set as default.  If that doesn't work you may want to install a sound card as the on-board sound or speaker port may have gone out on you.